# Syntax Error in Database Insert query vb.net

Tags: ms-access, webforms

if i remove ListBox in my form then it will run successfully..
MY CODE IS:

```
    Try
        Dim sqlconn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
        Dim sqlquery As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
        Dim connString As String
        connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\MyLaptop\Documents\dtbsform.accdb"
        sqlconn.ConnectionString = connString
        sqlquery.Connection = sqlconn
        sqlconn.Open()


        sqlquery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", nmTB.Text)

        If maleRB.Checked Then
            sqlquery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gen", maleRB.Text)
        Else
            sqlquery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gen", femaleRB.Text)
        End If


        For i As Integer = 0 To 3
            If courseDDL.SelectedIndex = i Then
                sqlquery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cor", courseDDL.SelectedItem.ToString)
            End If
        Next


        For i As Integer = 0 To langLB.Items.Count - 1
            If langLB.SelectedIndex = i Then
                sqlquery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lang", langLB.SelectedItem.ToString)
                MsgBox(langLB.SelectedItem.ToString)
            End If
        Next


        For i As Integer = 1 To 2
        If crktCB.Checked = True Then
            sqlquery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@favs", crktCB.Text)
        ElseIf ftblCB.Checked = True Then
            sqlquery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@favs", ftblCB.Text)
        End If
        Next


        For i As Integer = 0 To 2
            If hobCBL.SelectedIndex = i Then
                sqlquery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hob", hobCBL.SelectedItem.ToString)
            End If
        Next


        For i As Integer = 0 To 2
            If clgRBL.SelectedIndex = i Then
                sqlquery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@clg", clgRBL.SelectedItem.ToString)
            End If
        Next

        sqlquery.CommandText = "INSERT INTO dtbs (Name,Gender,Course,Language,Sports,Hobbies,College) VALUES (@Name,@gen,@cor,@lang,@favs,@hob,@clg)"
        sqlquery.ExecuteNonQuery()
        sqlconn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Comment: To make life easier on us, how about posting what your generated SQL looks like?  Where / what is the 'listbox' you mention?

Comment: Are you saying that using `sqlquery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lang", langLB.SelectedItem.ToString)` causes the query to fail while using `sqlquery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lang", "some dummy text")` works?  Or are you saying that `sqlquery.CommandText = "INSERT INTO dtbs (Name,Gender,Course,Language,Sports,Hobbies,College) VALUES (@Name,@gen,@cor,@lang,@favs,@hob,@clg)"` fails but `sqlquery.CommandText = "INSERT INTO dtbs (Name,Gender,Course,Sports,Hobbies,College) VALUES (@Name,@gen,@cor,@favs,@hob,@clg)"` works?  (Is `Language` a keyword in the database and needs to be `[Language]`?)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
sqlquery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lang", langLB.SelectedItem.ToString)
```

to

```
sqlquery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lang", langLB.SelectedItem.Text)
```